# How to implement quotas?

Tags: ubuntu

I am making a wordpress hosting site, and when I try to install a WordPress Plugin, a popup shows up, asking me for some information. The window basically means that wordpress does not have permissions to write to disk. When I change the wordpress folder with `chown www-data:www-data folder` it works, but now I don't have the advantage of monitoring that users disk quota.

Each wordpress installation has its own domain and is stored in folder /home/$USER/ftp/files/some-domain.com

some-domain.com folder belongs to www-data:www-data for plugin upload to function properly. But I need it to be $USER:$USER, but then, the upload problem appears. Is there a way for a non www-data:www-data to write to disk? I am using NGINX by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. The solution was to add a package called bindfs, which distinguishes the creator vs the owner of the folder.

```
#when inside the directory
chown -R $USER:www-data .
apt install bindfs
bindfs -u www-data -g www-data . .
```